# Add user if not exists in another table

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I need to add usernames to *users_waiting* table if they were not added to *users* table before.

```
var usernamesArray = ['test', 'test2'];
connection.query('REPLACE INTO users_waiting (username) VALUES ?', [usernamesArray]);
```

I'm using [node.js mysql client](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) and i have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options of doing it.
One of which is with `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
INSERT INTO <Table2> (...)
SELECT .... FROM <Source> t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM <Table1> s
                 WHERE t.id = s.id);
```

I don't think it's exactly what you need. But you can figure out the rest from this.